# Adicionar dias a uma data no mySQL e comparar com a data atual?

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo algumas condições em uma página do meu sistema, preciso colocar algo em meu `SELECT` para que no própio `SELECT` já entrasse em uma determinada condição.

A condição é a seguinte, preciso que esses 2 pontos sejam verdadeiros:

1. Se a data do pagamento for igual a 0000-00-00
2. Se passou 30 dias depois da data de emissão, e esse dia "pré-definido" for menor (menor porque já teria acabado o prazo de 1 mês) que a data de hoje.

*Uma hipótese minha foi adicionar + 30 dias na data do pagamento e comparar com a data de hoje*, porém nem sei se consigo fazer isso em um `SELECT`.

```
 SELECT nota_fiscal, emissao, valor, pagamento FROM emissao_nf WHERE pagamento = '0000-00-00'
```

É possível eu adicionar dias a todas as datas que estiverem registradas e ainda comparar com a data de hoje, tudo isso em um só `SELECT`?

Como posso estar fazendo isso dessa maneira ou até de outra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que vc precisa para poder "juntar" 2 condições é um "OR". Para a data, é sim possível somar. Vc pode fazer "data" + INTERVAL 30 DAY.

exemplo: `SELECT pagamento FROM emissao_nf WHERE pagamento = '0000-00-00' OR pagamento + INTERVAL 30 DAY > CURDATE()`

Vc pode experimentar essa query aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/869203/5

Comment: Funcionou, neste caso não usei o `OR` e sim o `AND`, precisava das duas condições, obrigado! +1

Comment: Neste caso penso que a sua query deverá ser sobre pagamento = '0000-00-00' (indicando que não houve um pagamento) **AND** de uma verificação sobre a emissão, ou data limite de pagamento. Pela pergunta parecia que ambas as suas condições eram sobre a coluna pagamento. @Samuel

Comment: Sim, `0000-00-00` indicando que não houve pagamento e uma verificação na data da emissão. Na sua resposta, só troquei o `OR` por `AND` e `emissao + INTERVAL 30 DAY < CURDATE()`